# Router with high receiver sensitivity?

Tags: router

The router will take signals out of my ISP router on the second floor and "repeat" the signals to every body on the first floor.

Price range $200.

I am using 2 router now.

One is xiaomi router

Another is TP-LINK 196108

The former is doing fine. I am using it right now. However, when I tried to run some mining algorithm suddenly the internet broke. The connection between the router to the ISP router becomes "bad"

And it's always happening.

I look on the web and I found that I have to find routers with high receiver sensitivity.

There are a bunch of choices

http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=29619&sid=59386f455c37988c6ea0f5f209ca8bec

says I should go for
802.11ac router instead of 802.11n? That seems to do more with speed instead of range. 802.11ac seems to have even less range than 802.11n

My problem is in how well the router deal with my ISP router on the second floor. It seems that the transmission of data across all devices on the same first floor is fine. All devices at my home can easily access my first floor router.

It's just that when too many devices connect to the same router, then connections start becoming problematic.

So basically I need a router on first floor that

1. Have high receiver sensitivity so it can detect and communicate with my ISP router on second floor
2. Have strong power too. I am sure it also has to transmit data to my ISP router on second floor.
3. Optional: Have dual connections. So can connect 802.11ac and 802.11 n. My xiaomi wireless is like that. So I can connect to both. If not, many of my devices won't be able to access it[image]

Actually what I really need is more of a "booster". I am not sure if signals from ISP routers are using 2.4 ghz frequency or 5ghz frequency. How do I find out?

I also wants to measure signal strength of my ISP booster so I can get better number. Any way how should I do so?  That way I can ask for -80 db signal sensitivity rather than "high" signal sensitivity receiver.

Comment: So what you need is a "repeater", that picks up the ISP router's wifi signal and re-broadcasts it (under the same security and SSID configuration)?

Comment: YES. However, often a router does the job.